# Save javascript object to json file on the server/localhost?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a local environment setup on my machine for my web app (ex: my.app). Currently my homepage consist of grid widgets that can be moved around on the layout. If the user wants to save their current layout, they click a button to save the layout to my server. I tried a php method, but nothing so far has seemed to work for me.

```
var layout = {
    user: "john doe",
    widgets: ["widget1", "widget2", "widget3"],
    layout_name: "my layout"
};

$.ajax({
    url: "/app/data/json.php",
    data: { json: JSON.stringify(defaultLayout) },
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST"
});
```

Then I have a php file json.php that's suppose to write to my server/localhost

```
<?php

    $json = $_POST['json'];
    $file = fopen('jsonfile.json', 'w+');

    fwrite($file, $json);
    fclose($file);

?>
```

When the code runs, nothing seems to happen. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help me save a javascript object to a JSON file on my server/localhost.

This is the response I'm getting back.

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: json in <b>/Users/me/Sites/my/app/data/json.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fopen(jsonfile.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied in <b>/Users/me/Sites/my/app/data/json.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/Users/me/Sites/my/app/data/json.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/Users/me/Sites/my/app/data/json.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: To add to @PedroLobito's comment, Does the directory you are writing to have permissions to be written to?

Comment: Have you checked whether the file was actually created? You didn't mention any error, looking to your code it should do nothing than create that file.

Comment: `defaultLayout` is undefined by the way!

Comment: @JorgeCampos the file wasn't created. I added an error log to the main question.

Comment: The error is quite clear. Your script doesn't have permission to create the file. You have to set the right permissions to the user that is running your script and set the right write permission on the folder the script is trying to write to.